# Err when try to instantiate Chaincode "failed to deserialize creator identity, err msp usermsp is unknown"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using Basic network with my changed organizations "user" and "legaldocxauth" and fabcar chaincode to run with it (later i will change chaincode functions  according to my use case) but whenever i run startFabric.sh on instantiating chaincode it gives  error "**failed to deserialize creator identity, err usermsp msp is unknown"**

- Docker version latest 18.09.0
- I have changed other network files configtx , docker-compose yaml and
  crypto configtx Msps accordingly
- I have also tried other solutions(on stackoverflow) of similar problem but no luck :(

Here is code for Startfabric.sh

```
set -e

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1
starttime=$(date +%s)
LANGUAGE=${1:-"golang"}
CC_SRC_PATH=user/go
if [ "$LANGUAGE" = "node" -o "$LANGUAGE" = "NODE" ]; then
CC_SRC_PATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/fabcar/node
fi

# clean the keystore
rm -rf ./../client/hfc-key-store


docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=userMSP" -e  "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/user.example.com/users/Admin@user.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode install -n newCC -v 2.0 -p "$CC_SRC_PATH" -l "$LANGUAGE"
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=userMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/user.example.com/users/Admin@user.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n newCC -l "$LANGUAGE" -v 2.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('userMSP.member','legaldocxauthMSP.member')"
sleep 10
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=userMSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/user.example.com/users/Admin@user.example.com/msp" cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n newCC -c '{"function":"initLedger","Args":[""]}'

printf "\nTotal setup execution time : $(($(date +%s) - starttime)) secs ...\n\n\n"
printf "Start by installing required packages run 'npm install'\n"
printf "Then run 'node enrollAdmin.js', then 'node registerUser'\n\n"
printf "The 'node invoke.js' will fail until it has been updated with valid arguments\n"
printf "The 'node query.js' may be run at anytime once the user has been registered\n\n"
```

Comment: Basic network using static info to create the channel.  Unlike first-network, it does not actually regenerate the genesis block or channel config.  Did you run the `generate.sh` script prior to your start script?

Comment: Yes. I ran the generate.sh before running anything else to create crytpo material for these organizations.

Comment: Strangely if i set CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=userMSP to Org1msp or anything else it throws error "Failed to deserialize creator identity , Expected Msp id userMsp ,Recieved Org1Msp

Comment: @GariSingh do you have some idea about it ?